# Clarification on deductive consequence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The *Standford Encyclopedia on Philosophy* page on [Classical Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#3) has the following theorem:

**Theorem 12.** A set Γ is consistent if and only if there is a formula θ such that it is not the case that Γ ⊢ θ.

Can someone explain the negation at the end: "*such that it is not the case that Γ ⊢ θ*". I was expecting this to be in the affirmative, "*such that it **is** the case...*". Does it have anything to do with Γ being contingent: satisfiable and falsifiable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a consistent set need not be falsifiable.  The intuition behind the definition is that consistency means that *not* too much should be deducible from $\Gamma$.  If absolutely every statement were deducible, then that would include various statements that contradict each other.

Often people define consistency to mean that it should not be possible to deduce two explicitly contradictory statements, i.e., statements of the form $\theta$ and not-$\theta$.  You should check (if your reference didn't do it for you) that (for classical logic) this is equivalent to the definition you quoted.

Comment: Sorry if this straying too far but how does *consistency* relate to completeness? I thought completeness meant you can express anything, including contradictions. I have another definition of completeness: *if Γ is consistent, then it is satisfiable*.

Comment: @Student You seem to be referring to two different notions of completeness. One is that a language (in the case of propositional logic, that would be a set of connectives) is complete if it allows you to express everything. The other is that a deductive system or a set of axioms is complete if it allows you to prove all the statements that are always true. It is not difficult to prove that a deductive system for classical logic is complete in the latter sense if and only if all consistent sets of sentences are satisfiable.

Comment: thanks for that. I've been struggling with these 2 definitions, thinking they were one.